# Disappearance of dataset rows when is built a recipe

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I upload the dataset into the storage of google cloud ai. Next, I open the flow in dataprep and put there the dataset. When I made the first recipe (without any step already) the dataset has approximately half of its original rows, that is, 36 234 instead of 62 948.

I would like to know what could be causing this problem. Some missing configuration?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple thoughts . . .

---

### Data Sampling

Keep in mind that what's shown in the Dataprep editor is typically a *sample* of the data, not the full data (unless its very small).  If the full file was small enough to load, you should see the "Full Data" label up where the sample is typically shown:

[image: Google Cloud Dataprep navigation indicating that the full file has been loaded]

In other cases, what you're actually looking at is a sample, which will also be indicated:

[image: Google Cloud Dataprep navigation indicating that the current dataset has been sampled]

It's very beneficial to have an idea of how Dataprep's sampling works if you haven't reviewed the documentation already:
https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Overview-of-Sampling_90112099

---

### Compressed Sources:

Another issue I've noticed occasionally is when loading compresses CSVs. In this case, I've had the interface tell me that I'm looking at the "Full Data"—but the number of rows is incorrect. However, any time this has happened the job **does** actually process the full number of rows.